# Relative paths don't work in mod_xsendfile at Apache

Tags: apache2, x-sendfile

I have problem, with mod_xsendfile. When I send to Apache header with absolute path (like /home/foo/foo.txt ) everything works fine. But when I use relative links I get strange errors in Apache's logs.

```
X-Sendfile: ../test.txt
No such file or directory: xsendfile: cannot open file: test.txt


X-Sendfile: test.txt
No such file or directory: xsendfile: cannot open file: test.txt/test.txt


X-Sendfile: te%20st.txt
No such file or directory: xsendfile: cannot open file: te st.txt/te%20st.txt
```

This is my site configuration (I use mod_jk)

```
XSendFile on
XSendFilePath /home/user/binares/

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName serv1

    JkMount / ajp13
    JkMount /* ajp13

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Are you sure is shouldn't be ./test.txt

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to enable

```
XSendFileAllowAbove On
```

In order to send the files using relative links.